# ElasticSearch:sort by sum of top two after group

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, pipeline, aggregation, bucket

i want to this result sort by sum of top2 not all,first,group by class,example:A,B,C...,use term;second,sort by socre,get the top2;third,get the sum of top2 not not all;finally,sory by sum of top2

```
GET students/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_class": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "class"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_scores": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "score": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 2
          }
        },
        "top_score":{
            "sum": {
              "field": "score"
            }
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result================

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 36,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_class" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "c",
          "doc_count" : 15,
          "top_sales_hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 15,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "students",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "44",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "score" : 100,
                    "name" : "小23"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    100
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "students",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "39",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "score" : 37,
                    "name" : "小7"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    37
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "total_score" : {
            "value" : 238.0    #i want top2(100+37),not all
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "b",
          "doc_count" : 13,
          "top_sales_hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 13,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "students",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "24",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "score" : 100,
                    "name" : "小23"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    100
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "students",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "2",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "score" : 33,
                    "name" : "小红"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    33
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "total_score" : {
            "value" : 201.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "a",
          "doc_count" : 8,
          "top_sales_hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 8,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "students",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "score" : 23,
                    "name" : "小明"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    23
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "students",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "12",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "score" : 12,
                    "name" : "小23"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    12
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "total_score" : {
            "value" : 82.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

like this result,finally sort by sum of  top all,i want top two,how get the sum of top two

provider test data

```
POST /students/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"小明","class":"A","score":23}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"小红","class":"B","score":33}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"小丽","class":"C","score":2}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"name":"小明a","class":"A","score":8}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"name":"小红a","class":"B","score":3}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"name":"小丽a","class":"C","score":1}
{"index":{"_id":7}}
{"name":"小丽b","class":"C","score":10}
```